# How do critical hits work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Occasionally, when I hurt mobs in Beta 1.8, there's a brief sparkle effect. Apparently, this indicates a **critical hit**.

How does one score a critical hit? What does a critical hit actually do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two different types of critical hits: **Critical melee hits**, and **critical arrows**.

---

### Melee crits

These occur when the player strikes a mob while moving downwards. Jumping and being stuck in a cobweb count, but moving down a ladder or sinking in water do not. Additionally, you can't do critical hits while blinded.

A critical hit has a sparkle effect, and sometimes does more damage than a regular one. The damage bonus is random, and varies between purely visual (i.e. +0) to **+50% damage** (rounded down), **plus half a heart**.

For example, a normal hit with the Diamond Sword does **7 damage** (3.5 hearts), while a critical hit does between **7 and 11** (3.5 - 5.5 hearts).

---

### Critical arrows

The critical hit effect on an arrow indicates that it was charged fully; the damage bonus for those works the same as for melee critical strikes.

Comment: Do you have any source for this?

Comment: @mordi2k Nope, original research. I punched a bunch of mobs with different weapons, critical hits and normal, then finished them off with my fist of anger to see how much damage the first hit did. Then I made a table, and the above formula fits the pattern.

Comment: @mordi2k Well, *now* it's original research again, but based on the source code rather than experimentation. Less fun, but I can't be having with those random damage bonus stuff.

Answer (score 3):

you can score a critical hit by hitting a mob (passive or hostile) while falling or shooting a arrow that is "fully charged" at it. A critical hit from a Bow will deal double damage.

Comment: Not just while jumping. While *falling*. I've scored critical hits while floating in an ocean on the downward bounce. Also, you will *not* score a critical hit during the upward part of a jump.

Comment: I think it's while "falling", rather than while jumping (though jumping *involves* falling, so that's how you trigger it in most cases)

Comment: Double damage can't be true. Two hits from a Diamond Sword will kill a Creeper, but one critical hit won't.

Comment: everytime i hit with a fully charged arrow on a mob it 1 hit kills them

Comment: and beside why would you go so near a creeper to perform a critical hit which might leave you dead

Comment: @ProSay - you might be correct about *arrows* dealing double damage when fully charged, but lunboks was countering that that can't be right with *swords*.

Comment: i pretty sure its the same but who knows i might be wrong